# Symfony Forms embedded forms

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Following the symfony documentation I am trying to embed a collection to a form. But when sending a post request to my endpoint the embedded form with the People collection stays empty. 
My entities:

user.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    use Mapping\UserTrait;

    /**
     * @param Person $person
     */
    public function addPeople(Person $person)
    {
        $this->people->add($person);
        $person->setOwner($this);
    }

    /**
     * @param Person $person
     */
    public function removePeople(Person $person)
    {
        $this->people->removeElement($person);
    }
}
```

UserTrait.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Mapping;

use App\Entity\Person;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 */
trait UserTrait
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hash", type="string")
     */
    private $hash;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Email
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Person", mappedBy="owner", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $people;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
     */
    private $plainPassword;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->people = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->roles = ['ROLE_USER'];
        $this->isActive = 1;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId(int $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isActive(): bool
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $isActive
     */
    public function setIsActive(bool $isActive): void
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $email
     */
    public function setEmail(string $email): void
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getPeople(): \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
    {
        return $this->people;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $people
     */
    public function setPeople(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $people): void
    {
        $this->people = $people;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPlainPassword()
    {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $plainPassword
     */
    public function setPlainPassword(string $plainPassword): void
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of UserInterface: Get password hash.
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->hash;
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return ["User"];
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHash(): string
    {
        return $this->hash;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $hash
     */
    public function setHash(string $hash): void
    {
        $this->hash = $hash;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function updatedTimestamps(): void
    {
        $dateTimeNow = new \DateTime('now');
        $this->setUpdatedAt($dateTimeNow);
        if ($this->getCreatedAt() === null) {
            $this->setCreatedAt($dateTimeNow);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt(): \DateTime
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTime $updatedAt): void
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     */
    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTime $createdAt): void
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
    }

}
```

Person.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Person
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Person
{
    use Mapping\PersonTrait;
}
```

PersonTrait.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Mapping;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * Person
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 */
trait PersonTrait
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="family_name", type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $familyName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="given_name", type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $givenName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string")
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="birth_date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $birthDate;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="salutation", type="string")
     */
    private $salutation;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="string")
     */
    private $gender;

    /**
     * @var \App\Entity\User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="people")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $owner;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFamilyName()
    {
        return $this->familyName;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $familyName
     */
    public function setFamilyName($familyName)
    {
        var_dump($familyName);
        $this->familyName = $familyName;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGivenName()
    {
        return $this->givenName;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $givenName
     */
    public function setGivenName($givenName)
    {
        $this->givenName = $givenName;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle(): string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $title
     */
    public function setTitle(string $title): void
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getBirthDate(): \DateTime
    {
        return $this->birthDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $birthDate
     */
    public function setBirthDate(\DateTime $birthDate): void
    {
        $this->birthDate = $birthDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSalutation(): string
    {
        return $this->salutation;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $salutation
     */
    public function setSalutation(string $salutation): void
    {
        $this->salutation = $salutation;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGender(): string
    {
        return $this->gender;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $gender
     */
    public function setGender(string $gender): void
    {
        $this->gender = $gender;
    }

    /**
     * @return \App\Entity\User
     */
    public function getOwner(): \App\Entity\User
    {
        return $this->owner;
    }

    /**
     * @param \App\Entity\User $owner
     */
    public function setOwner(\App\Entity\User $owner): void
    {
        $this->owner = $owner;
    }
}
```

Now to my form types:

UserType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;


use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
            ->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class)
            ->add(
                "people",
                CollectionType::class,
                [
                    'entry_type' => PersonType::class,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                ]
            );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'data_class' => User::class,
                'csrf_protection' => false
            ]
        );
    }

}
```

PersonType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;


use App\Entity\Person;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PersonType extends AbstractType
{


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('familyName', TextType::class)
            ->add('givenName', TextType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'data_class' => Person::class,
                'csrf_protection' => false,
            ]
        );
    }

}
```

Using this Types I am now trying to register a user and create a Person and add it to the user using this code:

```
/**
     * @Route("/register")
     * @param Request $request
     * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
     */
    public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
        $form->submit($request->request->all());

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
            $user->setHash($password);

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();
            return new Response("ok", 300);
        }
        return new Response("not ok", 500);

    }
```

My problem now is that when I send a post request with postman with following parameters and content:

```
email: test@test.de 
plainPassword: test1234  
people.familyName: testLastname 
people.givenName: testFirstname
```

I get the following error which means that it does not recognize the data for the person entity

> "This form should not contain extra fields."

How do I make symfony forms to recognize that people.givenName and people.familyName are meant to create a instance of Person

Edit: comment by u_mulder suggested to change the post body to person[0].givenName and now I am getting the error message

> This value is not valid.

Comment: Collection means that there's array of subitems. So, subitems should be some how indexed like `people[0].familyName: testLastname` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks actually a nice hint thanks for that! I will test it!

Comment: After changing this I get "this value is not valid"

Comment: Saying that givenName "TestFirstname" is not valid

Comment: can you post the view of your form please?

Comment: Like I explained in the question I am using postman to generate a POST request

Comment: Go ahead and render your form, fill in a few values and post.  Make sure everything works and then look at the posted data.  The Symfony forms component uses a somewhat involved element naming convention in order to map the posted data back to objects.  Once you know the exact format then you can go back to using postman if you wish.  And yes the answer below is trying to fix the symptoms and not the underlying cause.

Comment: @Cerad and you don't debugging the request data in the controller is enough? Why would I need a rendered form for that?

Comment: But actually you are right that there was a problem with the request content. :D

Comment: Because I am pretty sure your element names that you are using are wrong.  Rendering a form will tell you exactly what the names are.  Once you know those for sure then you can get rid of the rendered form.  Again, the form component uses it's own naming pattern.  And don't act so surprised that I was right.  Humor.

Comment: @Cerad the problem was actually really simple: I need to name the parameter people[0][familyName] instead of people[0]["familyName"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two problems which had to be fixed. First hint from u_mulder was that I have to use the index for people since its a collection. So instead of

```
people["givenName"]
```

I had to use

```
people[0]["givenName"]
```

Second mistake was that the structure of the postman body was wrong. Instead of

```
people[0]["givenName"]
```

I had to remove the quotes.

```
people[0][givenName]
```

After fixing both problems the forms work as expected.